# Return filtered Object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects that I want to filter and return a new array similar to the original but only with people who have hobbies. What's the best way?

```
const people =[
{id: 1, hobbies: [ {extraSports: false, category: [{isHobbie: true, hobbieType: 'paint'}, {isHobbie: false, hobbieType: 'work'}]},
                   {extraSports: true, category: [{isHobbie: false, hobbieType: 'work'}, {isHobbie: true, hobbieType: 'soccer'}]}
                 ]},
{id: 2, hobbies: [ {extraSports: false, category: [{isHobbie: true, hobbieType: 'draw'}, {isHobbie: false, hobbieType: 'work'}]},
                   {extraSports: true, category: [{isHobbie: true, hobbieType: 'tennis'}, {isHobbie: true, hobbieType: 'soccer'}]}
                 ]},
                 ]
```

expected result:

```
const peopleWithHobbies =[
{id: 1, hobbies: [ {extraSports: false, category: [{isHobbie: true, hobbieType: 'paint'}]},
                   {extraSports: true, category: [{isHobbie: true, hobbieType: 'soccer'}]}
                 ]},
{id: 2, hobbies: [ {extraSports: false, category: [{isHobbie: true, hobbieType: 'draw'}]},
                   {extraSports: true, category: [{isHobbie: true, hobbieType: 'tennis'}, {isHobbie: true, hobbieType: 'soccer'}]}
                 ]},
                 ]
```

My incomplete approach:

```
people.flatMap(person => person.hobbies).flatMap(hobbies => hobbies.category).filter(category => category.isHobbie == true)
```

Comment: u need 3 level nesting map(map(filter)) i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to modify the underlying data, you'll need to `map()` at every level:

```
const result = people.map(({ hobbies, ...peopleProps }) => ({
  ...peopleProps,
  hobbies: hobbies.map(({ category, ...hobbyProps }) => ({
    ...hobbyProps,
    category: category.filter(({ isHobbie }) => isHobbie)
  }))
}));
```

---

**Complete snippet:**

```js
const people = [{
    id: 1,
    hobbies: [{
        extraSports: false,
        category: [{
          isHobbie: true,
          hobbieType: 'paint'
        }, {
          isHobbie: false,
          hobbieType: 'work'
        }]
      },
      {
        extraSports: true,
        category: [{
          isHobbie: false,
          hobbieType: 'work'
        }, {
          isHobbie: true,
          hobbieType: 'soccer'
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    hobbies: [{
        extraSports: false,
        category: [{
          isHobbie: true,
          hobbieType: 'draw'
        }, {
          isHobbie: false,
          hobbieType: 'work'
        }]
      },
      {
        extraSports: true,
        category: [{
          isHobbie: true,
          hobbieType: 'tennis'
        }, {
          isHobbie: true,
          hobbieType: 'soccer'
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
];

const result = people.map(({ hobbies, ...peopleProps }) => ({
  ...peopleProps,
  hobbies: hobbies.map(({ category, ...hobbyProps }) => ({
    ...hobbyProps,
    category: category.filter(({ isHobbie }) => isHobbie)
  }))
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: If the category is an empty what is the best approach to not show that hobbie?

Comment: Add a filter on the first map level to filter out hobbies for which the category is empty.